# The plugin has been used here?

Tags: plugins

I saw this page and unfortunately do not have access to access the administration panel.

http://www.paulvanesch.com/?page_id=1751

Does anyone know what kind of plugin was used to retrieve this information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are seeing there, the whole site seems to be just missing with "To change this page, upload your website into the public_html directory" error message.

From the quick search on logo it seems to be coming from DirectAdmin control panel. No WordPress in sight...